# php is compiled language or Interpreted language?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is PHP compiled or interpreted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1514676/is-php-compiled-or-interpreted)

i know some things about PHP

PHP stands for PHP: Hypertext Preprocessor 
PHP is a server-side scripting language, like ASP 
PHP scripts are executed on the server 
PHP supports many databases (MySQL, Informix, Oracle, Sybase, Solid, PostgreSQL, Generic ODBC, etc.) 
PHP is an open source software 
PHP is free to download and use

i want to know whether it is compiled or interpreted langauge with reason?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP is an Interpreted Language : the code you write in your scripts is interpreted *-- at least, that's the default.*

Wikipedia defines an [**interpreted language**](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Interpreted_language) as

> a programming language in which
>   programs are 'indirectly' executed
>   ("interpreted") by an interpreter
>   program

In the case of PHP, your PHP scripts are interpreted by the PHP executable *(which can be embedded in an Apache module -- but the idea remains)*.

Notes, though, that there are compilers available *(but that's not the default setup you'll find in most situations)* -- see [wikipedia](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/PHP#Compilers) for a list.