# How to encrypt PHP files

Tags: php, performance, obfuscation, loading, pagespeed

I know there were few topics written already about this but no one answered it correctly.  Is there any tool or source that encrypt (or other name) php files or php source into bytecode or binary code that can't be read by people.

Some more clue will be, there are some PHP files when you trying to open it in linux it gives you a message stating "this file might be in binary would you like to view it".

Also, I 'v heard from someone that encrypted PHP files are much faster than normal php, is this true and if so, has anyone measured the difference yet?

Comment: Are you sure it isn't compiled instead of encrypted?

Comment: Shortanswer... No.

Long answer...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/232736/code-obfuscator-for-php/232767#232767

Comment: You probably mean compile rather than encrypt.  It is discussed [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1514676/is-php-compiled-or-interpreted

Comment: I am after encryption but if there is any program that compiles it to binary or bytecode that will be even nicer. Only if the extension stays as php not phb or c.

Answer (score 3):

there are several engines that provide a good encryption like [Zend Guard](http://www.zend.com/en/products/guard/), but they are never 100% protected.

as for performance, from my opinion I don't think it will be faster as it has to decrypt and the run the scripts.

Comment: "but they are never 100% protected" - Did u break it? Do you know anyone who breaks it? Ask russian people, they cannot yet XD... so, until no one can break it, it's 100% safe. Yes, we know, 99%? XD

Answer (score 0):

You can use php encoder from [ioncube](http://www.ioncube.com/sa_encoder.php) or [Zend Guard](http://www.zend.com/en/products/guard/) but there are others....