# PHP slow in large Iterations

Tags: java, php, eaccelerator

For Benchmarking PHP with iterations, I have considered a large for loop

```
for($j=0;$j<20000000;$j++)
    ;
```

Executing the same takes around **2.5 seconds** in PHP 5.4 with eAccelerator enabled

The same loop in .jsp file takes around **15 milliseconds**

```
for(int j=0;j<20000000;j++)
    ;
```

Why is there such a huge difference between both of them? Is there a way to make it work faster in PHP

Comment: 15 ms sounds like it was optimized out :/

Answer (score 4):

At 15ms the loop was probably optimized by the [JIT](http://java.dzone.com/articles/just-time-compiler-jit-hotspot).  Unless you're using [the HipHop VM](https://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=10150415177928920), your  [PHP loop doesn't really stand a chance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1514676/is-php-compiled-or-interpreted).

Keep in mind that the performance of a tight loop is hardly representative of relative performance in the real world with real workloads.  Check out 
[The Computer Language Benchmarks Game](http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/) instead -- and even *their* far more meaningful measurements are to be taken with a grain of salt.

Comment: going through the mentioned benchmarks, it does seem that PHP is lower in many aspects than Java, http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/u32/php.php

Comment: Not surprised, Java has JIT.

Comment: It's likely that the Java compiler has completely optimized out the loop. The code has no side-effect. A dead-code elimination algorithm would be able to see that.

Comment: Interestingly enough the compiler itself has not optimized the loop out.  

      Code:
       0:   iconst_0
       1:   istore_1
       2:   iload_1
       3:   ldc     #2; //int 20000000
       5:   if_icmpge       14
       8:   iinc    1, 1
       11:  goto    2
       14:  return

Performance through JIT is comparable with native C/C++ (~20ms on modern harwadre.)

Comment: @vladr >> to be taken with a grain of salt << That puts the emphasis in the wrong place: the measurements shown on the benchmarks game website are exactly what they claim to be -- the problem is that they are not measurements of programs doing the task Akash is trying to solve; the danger is that Akask will generalize from those very few measurements without considering and understanding that step in his thinking.

Answer (score 0):

These types of micro benchmarks should be of no concern.

Anyway this loop is slightly faster:

```
$i = 20000000;
while($i--);
```

http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/u32/compare.php?lang=java&lang2=php

Comment: I would take 15ms over 2.5s any day of the week; "of no concern" would apply to maybe 15ms vs 100ms, but once you cross the "seconds" threshold, delays are quite noticeable.

Comment: @newfurniturey Looping something 20 million times, the actual loop time should be insignificant.