# Missing concatenation part in PHP

Tags: php

Here is the code:

```
 <?php 

      for($i =0, $x = 100 ; $i<1; $i++){

      echo $x .  'y' . $i+1 . ' = '. $i*$x . ' <br>';
      }

    ?>
```

My Expected Output was: 100 y 1 = 0

But the actual result was: 101 = 0;

Where did 'y' go?

https://ideone.com/n9HYGp

Comment: there is no error in your code and your output will be : 100 y 1 = 0

Comment: wrong. The OUTPUT is 101 = 0.  You can check

Comment: https://ideone.com/n9HYGp

Comment: I think you should've expected the `100y1 = 0 `!!

Comment: typo error.  sorry. @ someone you are right

Comment: It's just because of [operator precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) of PHP that you've ignored!!

Comment: i deliberately ignored  just to show you guys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.` have more operator precedence than `+`.

```
echo $x .  'y' . $i+1 = 101
```

Because it will operate as

```
echo ($x .  "y" . $i)+1 ;
```

This is what happens.

```
$x3=  ($x .  "y" . $i); //100y0
$u = $x3+1 ;  //101
```

You are doing `+` operation on a string. So the first digits before any characters will be taken as integer value.

Eg:

```
10y0g8 = 10
t10  =0
```

By doing an Arithmetic Operation, interpreter will convert string to integer, and it `will discard all other characters`. so `100y+1 = 101` it won't be `101y`

Comment: In your answer. $x3 = 100y0; then you add +1 in $x3 which becomes 101.. very confusing.. how 100y0 +1 = 101 ??

Comment: ok i can understand what you say. 100y0 +1 = 101... Fine ... why the answer is 101 and not 101y where did y go?

Comment: ok beside this + operator, the compiler should have writter y after 101.. that what i say.

Comment: is it what you said.. compiler will discard all other characters because it will convert string to integer.. .... CLEARED NOW THANKS MAN

Comment: For the record, [it's not the compiler! it's the interpreter](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1514676/3709765) :)

Comment: thanks for the correction. I learned. :) One day i will be in a position to give better answers.. ONE DAY :)

Answer (score 1):

as explained in the above (Subin Thomas) answer the addition of 1 with the varchar value like 100y0 will add 1 with 100(the first occurence of integer). the following code will work as you expected

```
<?php 

  for($i =0 ,$x = 100; $i<1; $i++){

  echo $x .  'y' . ($i+1) . ' = '. $i*$x . ' <br>';
  }

?>
```

Comment: Man you are absolutely right. But again if you donot put brackets around ($i+1), then why it becomes 101 = 0

Comment: $x = 100. and y will concat to it as 100y when it added $i+1=1 then 100y+1. it will take first occurence of integer that is 100+1=101.

Comment: ok as u said it will take first occurrence of integer, ok fine, then where did y go?

Comment: you are using + operator right. this will take any characters before it as integer y is not an integer so it removes "y".

Answer (score 0):

To test :

```
<?php 

  for($i =0, $x = 100 ; $i<1; $i++){

  echo $x .  'y' . ($i+1) . ' = '. $i*$x . ' <br>';
  }

?>
```

Comment: Obviously because of higher precedence of ().. But what if we donot put brackets..  just give explanation to the actual answer..

Comment: Have a look to http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php post #56...