# How does PHP parse functions

Tags: php, php-internals

Well I confused by behavior of PHP when parsing a PHP file. I am reading this since long that

> The PHP language is interpreted

So I have code

```
var_dump(function_exists('abc')); exit;
function abc() {
    return;
}
```

`var_dump` should print `false` as per my assumption but it print `bool(true)`.

Can somebody please help me to understand this behavior?

Comment: it's pre-compiled before running, not interpreted while running AFAIK

Comment: @RST Any ref or link for that ?

Comment: function abc() was called before exit; (using function_exists) that's why it returns 'true'. Even if you define the function after exit and it is called before exit, it still execute.

Comment: what I meant was, using function_exists(), the function abc() was called because it searched if that certain function exists.

Comment: @RenCamp I know the same is happening that what you told but any link for this behavior ? Or where it has been written ?

Comment: [Reference](http://laruence-wordpress.stor.sinaapp.com/uploads/the-php-life-cycle.pdf)

Comment: reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php. It states that "Checks the list of defined functions, both built-in (internal) and user-defined, for function_name"

Comment: @RenCamp - `function_exists()` will not call function `abc()` at all, it simply checks if there is a definition for function `abc()` in the global functions list

Comment: just what @RST said, it's pre-compiled

Comment: @MarkBaker, my bad. it's checked, not called.

Comment: What you see here is often called "function hoisting". Non-conditional definitions of functions are "hoisted" to the top of the script.

Comment: @NikiC Thanks but you should have added this as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1514737/1790644).

In short, it is compiled into a type of bytecode at runtime and then interpreted - in doing this, you will have the definitions for your functions available, even if they appear at the very end.

Comment: Okay so finally PHP is not just interpreted as people say?

Comment: Well it is, but the code has to be turned into something readable by the interpreter, this bytecodeish form has your code optomized for the interpreter.

Comment: Well it make sense. Thanks Matt.

Answer (score 0):

[function_exist](http://php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php) will Checks the list of defined functions, both built-in (internal) and user-defined, for function_name. So, php interpreter checks if the function with the name is defined in the bytecode which is complied before interpreted.