# sprintf and place holders processing order

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following PHP code inside a Wordpress template that gets the user search query text and insert it into a string:

```
$name = sprintf( esc_html__( 'Search Results for: %s'),  get_search_query());
```

The line as mentioned works, and the result is something like:

```
"Search Results for Doggy Bags"
```

What I don't understand is, why does it work? Shouldn't `esc_html__()` run first before `sprintf()` has had the chance to replace the placeholder (%s) inside the former function to the search query term?

Thanks,

Comment: You might find some of the answers to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1514676/is-php-compiled-or-interpreted relevant

Comment: I might also add that in this case the `esc_html__()` is a waste of time, since there’s nothing in the string which needs escaping.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. `esc_html__()` runs first and returns its output to `sprintf()`.

The `esc_html__()` function returns [the translation of `Search Results for: %s` and escapes it for safe use in HTML output](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_html__/).

Its output if there are no defined translations for this string is `Search Results for: %s`. Effectively, it becomes:

`sprintf("Search Results for: %s",get_search_query());`

and then:

`sprintf("Search Results for: %s","Doggy Bags");`

Finally, it becomes:

`Search Results for: Doggy Bags`

Comment: Thanks. Based on this order of events, doesn't it mean that the value of `get_search_query()` doesn't get the `esc_html()` treatment, potentially leading to a security hole?

Comment: That seems right. You can prove this by specifying HTML tags in your search query.

Comment: @cocopuffs I know it’s a bit late, but you should accept this answer.